# C++ to C# Conversion with IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++

I am busy rewriting a piece of code from C++ in to C#

Currently I am stuck at the following

```
pCommBuf = new BYTE[nSize+SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE+SB_OEM_CHK_SUM_SIZE];
nReceivedBytes = comm_recv( pCommBuf, nSize+SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE+SB_OEM_CHK_SUM_SIZE, gCommTimeOut );
if( nReceivedBytes != nSize+SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE+SB_OEM_CHK_SUM_SIZE )
{
    if(pCommBuf)
        delete pCommBuf;
    return PKT_COMM_ERR;
}
memcpy(Buf, pCommBuf, SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE);
memcpy(pBuf, pCommBuf+SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE, nSize);
wReceivedChkSum = *(WORD*)(pCommBuf+nSize+SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE);
```

I have the code working up to this point

```
//memcpy(Buf, pCommBuf, SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE);
Marshal.Copy(pCommBuf, Buf, 0, (int)(SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE + SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE)); // This works
//memcpy(pBuf, pCommBuf+SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE, nSize);
```

I am not sure how to do `pCommBuf+SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE` in C#, pCommBuff is a `IntPtr` and in C++ `Byte*`

Comment: Do you need to keep all the C++-styled buffers? Can't you switch to C# streams?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.add?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to change the start offset for the 2nd copy :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE = 10;
        const int SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE = 10;
        const int SB_OEM_CHK_SUM_SIZE = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int nSize = 1024;
            byte[] nBuf = new byte[nSize];
            byte[] Buf = new byte[SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE + SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE];

            IntPtr pCommBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nSize + SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE + SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE + SB_OEM_CHK_SUM_SIZE);
            Marshal.Copy(nBuf, 0, pCommBuf, nSize);
            Marshal.Copy(pCommBuf + nSize , Buf, 0, (int)(SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE + SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The offset is [in the destination array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_Copy_System_IntPtr_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_). The OP wants to offset the `pCommBuf` which is `IntPtr`.

Comment: Did have my coffee this morning.  Fixed code.  Simply add nSize to pCommBuf.

Comment: No, you need to add `SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE` to `pCommBuf`, and not offset the destination.

Comment: With the code you've posted, you are [copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_Copy_System_IntPtr_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) `SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE + SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE` bytes from  `(pCommBuf + nSize)` into `Buf` starting at `Buf[0]`. You should be copying `nSize` bytes from `pCommBuf + SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE` into `Buf` starting at `Buf[0]`.

Comment: You first add nSize bytes and then have to skip nSize bytes with my code.  You are right only if the headers go before the nSize bytes.

Comment: I don't know where the headers go. I look at the C++ code in the question. It [copies](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) `nSize` bytes from `pCommBuf + SB_OEM_HEADER_SIZE+SB_OEM_DEV_ID_SIZE` into `pBuf`. Well, yes, that means the headers go before the nSize bytes.