# How to implement IComparable<Time> in my Struct?

Tags: c#, struct, icomparable

My code includes struct called `Time`.

I would like to implement `IComparable<Time>` interface in my struct to compare two variables of type 'Time'.

I've already did it with `IEquatable` and it works, but I can't figure out how to do it with `IComparable`.

Since `Time` consists of three variables (hours, min, sec) I can't simply consider each case in `if`. Or can I? Could you give me a hint how to code it? Thank you.

```cs
{    
    public struct Time : IEquatable<Time>, IComparable<Time>
    {
        private byte hours, minutes, seconds;

        public byte Hours { get { return hours; } }
        public byte Minutes { get { return minutes; } }
        public byte Seconds { get { return seconds; } }

        public Time(byte hh, byte mm, byte ss)
        {
            if (hh < 0 || hh > 24)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            if (mm < 0 || mm > 60)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            if (ss < 0 || ss > 60)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            this.hours = hh;
            this.minutes = mm;
            this.seconds = ss;
        }

        public Time(byte hh, byte mm) : this(hh, mm, default(byte)) { }

        public Time(byte hh) : this(hh, default(byte), default(byte)) { }

        public Time(string hms)
        {
            string[] arr = hms.Split(':');

            this.hours = Convert.ToByte(arr[0]);
            this.minutes = Convert.ToByte(arr[1]);
            this.seconds = Convert.ToByte(arr[2]);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object t)
        {
            if (t == null || this.GetType() != t.GetType()) return false;

            return (this.Hours == ((Time)t).Hours &&
                this.Minutes == ((Time)t).Minutes &&
                this.Seconds == ((Time)t).Seconds);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.GetHashCode();
        }

        // IEquatable
        public bool Equals(Time other)
        {
            return this.Equals((object)other);
        }

        public static bool operator == (Time t1, Time t2)
        {
            return t1.Equals(t2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Time t1, Time t2)
        {
            return !t1.Equals(t2);
        }

        // IComparable
        public int CompareTo(Time other)
        {
            if (this == other)
                return 0;

            // Code that compares two variables
        }

        public static bool operator > (Time t1, Time t2)
        {
            return t1.CompareTo(t2) == 1;
        }

        public static bool operator < (Time t1, Time t2)
        {
            return t1.CompareTo(t2) == -1;
        }

        public static bool operator >= (Time t1, Time t2)
        {
            return t1.CompareTo(t2) >= 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <= (Time t1, Time t2)
        {
            return t1.CompareTo(t2) <= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203058/discussion-on-question-by-mrsebastian-how-to-implement-icomparabletime-in-my-s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
public int CompareTo(Time other)
{
    var by_hour = this.Hours - other.Hours;
    if (by_hour != 0)
        return by_hour;

    var by_minute = this.Minutes - other.Minutes;
    if (by_minute != 0)
        return by_minute;

    return this.Seconds - other.Seconds;
}
```

Also change all places where you use the `Compare` method to account for the fact that [it can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.8#returns) return non-zero values other than 1 and -1.

Comment: Bad code!!!  You are removing the days and years.  All you want to do is is to truncate the time less than a second.

Comment: @jdweng `Time` != `DateTime` :)

Comment: @jdweng It would appear you need [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016350/c-to-c-sharp-conversion-with-intptr/59017303#comment104282612_59017303) coffee. Please read *the question* again. There is no `DateTime` and no `Tick`s.

Comment: @jdweng The OP just created a brand new date time object where the accuracy is a second. It would be helpful if you actually looked that up in the question.

Comment: @jdweng - a certain Pratchett quote comes to mind... this is **not** about `DateTime` or `Ticks`. This is about a user defined `struct`, that's just happend to be called `Time` and the question is basically: "How to compare a thing that has three properties in the sequence big, medium and small?" -- answer: check if the big part differs first, then the medium part, then the small part and return fast if any is different.

Comment: As I said I want to teach OP that code is not very robust.  Collection around midnight will not work.  Just answering a question does not give correct results if OPs do not understand all the issues.  The OP may be asking a bad question.

Comment: @jdweng Why is collection around midnight not robust? OPs requirement may be to have the resolution for seconds only. This is not about dates, only time of day.

Comment: We are playing a game of telephone and only getting what the OPs tells use, and not what the teacher expects.  The code will incorrectly order 11/24/19 11:00PM and 11/25/1:00 AM.  With date truncated, the second time will come before the first time.

Comment: @jdweng For the last time, there is no date component in this structure at all, nor there supposed to be one.